# C# bool not set correctly

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have some C# code that's attempting to do an LDAP search using a supplied computer name to determine whether or not the computer account is disabled. Most of this code was taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591681/using-c-how-do-you-check-if-a-computer-account-is-disabled-in-active-directory). The code in the example link works great and correctly displays true if I go disable an account in AD and false on computers that are active. The issue is that I can't exactly use the code in the manner it was originally presented, it must be used in the manner I have pasted it below. The problem with the below code is that it's always returning false, it doesn't seem to matter what computer name you pass to it. I also realize that the foreach loop is probably unneeded since I'm only trying to find one computer.

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace DynamicNamespace
{
    public class DynamicClass
    {
        public System.Boolean DynamicMethod(System.Boolean IsDisabled, System.String ComputerName)
        {
            //the string should be your a DC(domain controller)
            const string ldap = "LDAP://server-name";

            //DirectoryEntry is used for manipulating objects (users, computers)
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldap);

            //DirectorySearcher responds to a filter method for LDAP searches
            //http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5667 has a decent query guide
            DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

            //SAM Account Name was showing a $ sign at one point, using * for wildcard
            dSearch.Filter = String.Format("samAccountName={0}*", ComputerName);
            dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");
            dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl");

            SearchResultCollection results = dSearch.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                int userAccountControl = Convert.ToInt32(result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0]);
                string samAccountName = Convert.ToString(result.Properties["samAccountName"][0]);
                bool disabled = ((userAccountControl & 2) > 0);

                if (disabled == false)
                {
                    IsDisabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsDisabled = true;
                }
            }
            return IsDisabled;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many results are you getting in 'results'?  And why can't you just use IsDisabled = ((userAccountControl & 2) > 0);   ?

Comment: Why are you passing IsDisabled in as an argument if you are then updating the value and returning it?  Why not declare it in the local scope instead?

Comment: Try spitting out the results you get inside your `foreach (SearchResult result in results)` loop.

Comment: @RQDQ - A single, your idea is good for just setting it based on the result of the 2nd bit.

Comment: @RQDQ - Correction, it appears that it was getting more than one. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, the only problem is that you don't have a distinction between if the account does not exist and if it exists but is disabled.

You can do the following to detect if the account does not exists, it does not matter that you are doing a for loop because like you said it only does it once but if you like change it to below... (You have to change it to cater for the fact that it can return more than 1 results as well because you've got a * in your search filter)

```
  SearchResultCollection results = dSearch.FindAll(); 
  if (results.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Account not found.");
  else if (results.Count == 1)
        {
            SearchResult result = results[0];
            int userAccountControl = Convert.ToInt32(result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0]);
            string samAccountName = Convert.ToString(result.Properties["samAccountName"][0]);
            bool disabled = ((userAccountControl & 2) > 0);
            if (disabled == false)
            { IsDisabled = false; }
            else { IsDisabled = true; }
        }
  else 
      throw new Exception("More than 1 result found, please filter");
try
{
    bool res = dc.DynamicMethod(false, "Username");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message == "Account not found.")
    {
        //Do Something
    }
    else
        throw ex;
}
```

Obviously you can replace throwing an exception with something more appropriate...

Answer (score 2):

You are probably receiving more than one SearchResult and since you're using a loop `IsDisabled` will be assigned multiple times.

According to the [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5667) in your comments, you're doing a partial match:

```
PARTIAL MATCH......................(attribute={partial value}*)
```

If the supplied computer name is exact, why not use:

```
EQUALITY...........................(attribute=value)
```

Then you can remove the loop:

```
dSearch.Filter = String.Format("(samAccountName={0})", ComputerName);
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl");

SearchResult result = dSearch.FindOne();
bool disabled = (result != null) && ((userAccountControl & 2) > 0);
```

Comment: Yeah that's a good call, he even says he's not sure he needs the loop so it should be dropped.  You could even remove IsDisabled altogether and simply `return (result != null) && ((userAccountControl & 2) > 0);`

Comment: @Infotekka I like to view the result in the debugger. :)

Comment: Ha, yeah good point - sometimes I get carried away with compacting my code.

Comment: I just had a * in there because samAccountNames seem to sometimes have a $ after them. Thanks for the FindOne() method.

Answer (score 1):

You should step through the debugger to confirm this, but its possible that if you are passing `false` in as the first argument when you call this function and the search is not getting any results, then your function will return the same `false` value that you passed in to begin with through `IsDisabled`.