# How can I check whether the domain account of a computer got invalid (the trust is broken)?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, account

I must recognize notebooks whose `domain accounts` are no longer valid.

> Invalid domain accounts may happen due to several problems. Mostly the client got restored from a backup and afterwards the domain account is not valid any more

Int this case the behavour is:

- The user's logon works through `cached credentials`
- The user `has access to shares` and files on the server (NTLM)
- Access via `Kerberos does not work`

**Is there any possibility to check the validity of the computer account?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code I can find `invalid computer domain accounts`:

```
try
{
    string sMyComputer = "MyComputer"
    Domain computerDomain = Domain.GetComputerDomain(); // may! throw ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException if computer account is invalid 
    string sComputerDomain = computerDomain.Name;
    NTAccount acc_machine = new NTAccount(sComputerDomain, sMyComputer + "$"); 
    SecurityIdentifier sid = (SecurityIdentifier)acc_machine.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)); // always throws an SystemException if computer account is invalid
}
catch    
{ 
   // something is wrong with the account    
}
```

- sMyComputer + "$" is how the account name is stored in the active directory
- my experience is that the first exception is mostly not thrown and the return value is the correct name of the domain the computer had once a working computer account
- the second exception (SystemException) is always thrown if computeraccount is now invalid. The errocode is 80004005. (I had expected an IdentityNotMappedException)

EDIT:
corrected error in code